# Link failure when typedef declaration defines unnamed class

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, language-lawyer

Section `7.1.3[9]` of the C++11 standard states:

> If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first typedef-name declared by the declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage purposes only (3.5).

**[ Example:**

```
typedef struct { } *ps, S; // S is the class name for linkage purposes
```

**—end example ]**

This means that in the example below, `Foo` should be used as the name of the unnamed class and used for linkage purposes in the example below:

```
//foo1.cpp
typedef class
{
        public: int f();
} Foo;

int Foo::f()
{
        return 5;
}
```

Since `Foo::f()` is defined in `foo1.cpp`, the compiler should not complain.

```
//foo2.cpp
typedef class
{
    public: int f();
} Foo;

Foo foo;

int main()
{
    return foo.f();
}
```

However, I get a link error with `GCC 4.8`. Am I missing something?

```
$g++ foo1.cpp foo2.cpp
/tmp/ccMwHawT.o: In function `main':
713Y51.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `Foo::f()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: "If typedef declaration defines unnamed class (or enum), use first typedef-name declared to be that class type (or enum type) as class type (or enum type) for linkage purposes only." is broken English, and is not what's actually in the standard.

Comment: Fyi, the exact quote from C++ 11 [dcl.typeef] : "If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the first typedef-name declared by the declaration to be that class type (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for linkage purposes only (3.5)." (and 3.5 deserve serious perusing to understand what "linkage" *really* means, particularly in relation to an otherwise-unnamed class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right. There's nothing really to add from the standard other than what's already in your question.

This is a [long-standing bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7221) in GCC. clang agrees with your interpretation and accepts your program.